# Streaming Live audio to the browser - Alternatives to the Web Audio API?

Tags: streaming, web-audio-api, live-streaming

I am attempting to stream live audio from an iOS device to a web browser. The iOS device sends small, mono wav files (as they are recorded) through a web socket. Once the client receives the wav files, I have the Web Audio API decode and schedule them accordingly.

This gets me about 99% of the way there, except I can hear clicks between each audio chunk. After some reading around, I have realized the likely source of my problem: **the audio is being recorded at a sample rate of only 4k** and this cannot be changed. It appears that the Web Audio API's `decodeAudioData()` function does not handle sample rates other than 44.1k with exact precision resulting in gaps between chunks.

I have tried *literally everything* I could find about this problem (scriptProcessorNodes, adjusting the timing, creating new buffers, even manually upsampling) and none of them have worked. At this point I am about to abandon the Web Audio API.

Is the Web Audio API appropriate for this?
Is there a better alternative for what I am trying to accomplish?
Any help/suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As currently spec'ed, `decodeAudioData()` always resamples the encoded audio to the sample rate specified by `context.sampleRate`.  Unless you can change the sample rate of the output device, resampling has to be done somewhere.  There have been proposals for `decodeAudioData()` not to resample or `AudioContext()` to take a desired sample rate so that all resampling happens internally.  This would , I think, fix your clicks.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the FileAPI to put the files together and then play it with a normal audio object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas! [AudioFeeder.js](https://github.com/brion/audio-feeder) works wonders. I just specify the sampling rate of 4k, feed it raw 32 bit pcm data and it outputs a consistent stream of seamless audio! Even has built in buffer handling events, so no need to set any loops or timeouts to schedule chunk playback. I did have to tweak it a bit, though, to connect it to the rest of my web audio nodes and not just context.destination.

**Note**: AudioFeeder does automatically upsample to the audio context sampling rate. Going from 4k to 44.1k did introduce some pretty gnarly sounding artifacts in the highend, but a 48db lowpass filter (4 x 12db's) at 2khz got rid of them. I chose 2khz because, thanks to [Harry Nyquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), I know that a sampling rate of 4k couldn't have possibly produced frequencies above 2khz in the original file.

All hail Brion Vibbers