# Is it possible to use audio-feeder.js for live stream audio data?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, decoding, live-streaming

I am having websocket that delivers the stream audio data. While I decode the audio data using AudioContext().decodeAudioData(), the required audio is playing with some gap in between them. So as mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/37150660/3979414, I tried to use Audio-feeder.js. But its difficult to reproduce the live stream audio in audio-feeder.js

Can someone provide sample live stream data decoding using audio-feeder.js ?

Comment: What about MediaSource API? How are you retrieving the stream?

Comment: I tried the same as in the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/35881505/3979414. Need to check MediaSource API.

Comment: I tried MediaSource API, but it only supports Chrome 38+. Its not supported in firefox. I followed this link  [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/Media-Source-Extensions-for-Audio)

Comment: MediaSource has a quite decent [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource#Browser_compatibility) for this kind of API. Not sure where you saw it's not supported in FF.

Comment: Ok @Kaiido . Will check that in FF.

Comment: I'm using aac audio file. When I checked the support in chrome like in console >> **MediaSource.isTypeSupported("audio/aac")** . It results _true_. 

But when checked the same thing in FF, it shows "**_false & Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: audio/aac._**"

Comment: yes AAC is not free for codecs developpers, hence you'll rarely find it in opensource projects (e.g it's not supported by chromium either). Why don't you use ogg instead ?

Comment: Ok @Kaiido . I will try with ogg. 

BTW, Is there any other way to decode aac format ?